# How to add leading zeros to character field in SAS?

Tags: sas

I trying to figure out the following: I have SAS dataset 'ids' with character variable with different length such as idnum3, idnum897 or idnum2342345. Need to create each ID with the same length and add leading zeros to have soething like '000000idnum3','0000idnum897', idnum2342345. I tried many options but it seems nothing works. Any suggestions please. Thanks!

Comment: can you edit your question to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 6):

Two general approaches are useful here.

First, if the field is entirely numeric, you use the `Zw.d` format.

```
idnum=put(input(idnum,8.),z8.);
```

If it's not entirely numeric, then you use `repeat()` to generate the zeros.  Use `length()` to find out how many you need.  `Repeat` takes two arguments - the character to be repeated, and the number of repeats to add to the original.  That number will be one less than the intuitive number: `repeat('0',3)` = `0000`.

So:

```
  if length(idnum) lt 8 then idnum = cats(repeat('0',8-1-length(idnum)),idnum);
```

Make sure your ID number variable has enough length to fit the full ID, also, or this won't work.

Longer example:

```
data have;
input idnum $8.;
datalines;
idn2
idn234
idn23456
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  if length(idnum) lt 8 then idnum = cats(repeat('0',8-1-length(idnum)),idnum);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. The code did not produced desired outcome. For example for the 'idnum3' instead of creating '000000idnum3' it produced only '000000'. Please advise.

Comment: Sounds like your variable length isn't long enough.

Comment: Excellent, great solution, it is exactly what I was looking for. I completely forgot to assign the length --- after that I got the desired output. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have this issue on a daily basis. The format of Zn. should give you what you need. For example, lets say you have SSN (character numbers) where an individual has a social of `000012345`. If you were to read this in from excel or a text file, you might end up with `12345`. You can use the format of `Zn.` to create your leading zeroes -

```
Data Want;
Set Have;
SSN = PUT(VALUE,Z9.);
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a character variable, mix of letters and numbers. Z format gives an error "the format $Z was not found or could not be loaded".

Answer (score 2):

If it's more intuitive, you can also use translate in conjunction with the right function. The idea is that you right-align the values in a field and replace the spaces created with zeros.

```
data have;
    input id $16.;
    datalines;
    idnum3 
    idnum897  
    idnum2342345
    ;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    want = translate(right(id), "0", " ");
run;
```

Comment: Good idea, I like this one more than the `repeat` function, as long as there aren't meaningful spaces in the ID variable.